# How to set /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding to 1 by default in network namespaces?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, network-namespace

By default, when I create a network namespace, I get:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding=0
```

Even if it is 1 in my root network namespace or in /etc/sysctl.conf. I was wondering where network namespaces get the default config and how to change that. I'd like to have that set to 1 so that new network namespaces get that config by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thikn I found the answer. In general, network namespaces inherit the parameters of the root namespace. This is controlled by devconf-inherit-init-net settings as explained here:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/net.html#devconf-inherit-init-net

By default all ipv4 parameters are inherited but not ipv6

Comment: Nice find. The default does make some sense. Most of the time containers will configure IPv6 very differently to the host, and starting with the default configuration is reasonable in this scenario. By contrast inheriting IPv4 configuration has been done for so long that most everyone expects it to happen, and changing that to not inherit would confuse people and break existing applications in unforeseen ways. And Linus always says to never break userspace....