# Can I change the default sysctl values in grub?

Tags: linux-networking, network-namespace

When using kernels older than 5.1, if a user creates a network namespace, it starts with the default sysctl values. Even if the root namespaces changed those values with sysctl, the new network namespaces will still use the default values.For example, `proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding` is always 0 because that's the default value.

If I understand correctly, those are default values set by the kernel and I was wondering if it is possible to change those via GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX or any other way. Note that I don't want to access the network namespace and change the parameter via sysctl (or echo /proc/sys/net....), I'd like to change the default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is available only since kernel 5.8, as described in this UL SE Q/A: [How to set sysctl using kernel command line parameter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558802/how-to-set-sysctl-using-kernel-command-line-parameter):

> [`sysctl.*=   [KNL]`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt?h=v5.8#n4994)
>
> ```
>       Set a sysctl parameter, right before loading the init
>       process, as if the value was written to the respective
>       /proc/sys/... file. Both '.' and '/' are recognized as
>       separators. Unrecognized parameters and invalid values
>       are reported in the kernel log. Sysctls registered
>       later by a loaded module cannot be set this way.
>       Example: sysctl.vm.swappiness=40
> ```

So combined with [`devconf_inherit_init_net`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/net.rst?h=v5.8#n332) found by OP [in a previous Q/A](https://serverfault.com/questions/1078815/how-to-set-proc-sys-net-ipv6-conf-all-forwarding-to-1-by-default-in-network-nam), **starting from kernel 5.8**, but not before and thus not before 5.1 either, adding through GRUB these two kernel parameters:

```
sysctl.net.core.devconf_inherit_init_net=1 sysctl.net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

will achieve the intended goal.